# I'm new to Java and I need to write a program that asks for the number of rows, columns, and RGB values, then draws a design that many times

Tags: java

I've got it to draw the design and to accept the color values but can't get it to draw it multiple times and I don't know what to do.  I think it may be just drawing the image on top of itself multiple times, but don't know how to fix this.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
public class Pattern {

public static void main(String[] args) {

             DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(540, 540);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0 - 30;
    System.out.print("Number of rows (1-10): ");
    int numInt = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Number of columns (1-10): ");
    int numIntagan = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Red Value (0-255): ");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Green Value (0-255): ");
    int b = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Blue Value (0-255): ");
    int c = in.nextInt();


   for (numInt = numInt; numInt >= 1; numInt--) {
        Color USER = new Color(a, b, c);
        g.setColor(USER);
        g.drawOval(x + 50, x + 50, 50, 50);
        g.drawRect(x + 50, x + 50, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you are not even calling the `drawCircle` method - what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: Who ever is teaching you/suggesting that you use `getGraphics` should be shot.  This is NOT how custom painting works in Swing.  Start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details about how painting works. Don't mix console/procedural based coding with GUI/event driven based coding, their requirements differ greatly

Comment: Maybe you should also have a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: I had messed up the code and had to edit the post sorry

Comment: If you're trying tile shapes, the coordinate value is going to have do be different each time you draw one.  You pass (x + 50, x + 50) each time, so, as you suspected, you are simply drawing shapes on top of eachother.

Comment: This is one of the strangest for loops I've seen. Why not use a standard for loop?

Comment: @c_dubs I need the images to be right next to each other, each image is 50 pixels wide, how would I set the location so that it changes each by 50 pixels each time?

Comment: @MartijnBurger because I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: If you're tiling the shapes in some sort of rectangle, you will need a nested loop, where you iterate over all the possible combinations of rows and columns.  You need a way to translate the row and column number into x and y coordinates.

Comment: I would suggest you took a step back and start with some basic Java training. We can provide an answer, but I don't think that would be usefull. There are many other code examples you can study.

Comment: Tutorials here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll try to redeem myself for the negative and unhelpful answer that I posted earlier.  My understanding is that you are trying to tile circles and rectangles in 50x50 squares, and the user can specify how many rows and columns of tiles to draw.  What you'll need to do is iterate over every row/column coordinate. For each row/column coordinate, you will need to determine appropriate pixel coordinate, and then draw the shapes accordingly.  With drawRect and drawOval, the coordinate arguments refer to the location of the top left corner of the shape to be drawn.  Remember that when talking about pixel coordinates, y = 0 at the top of the screen, and x = 0 at the left of the screen.  This means that to draw a 50x50 square at row 0 column 0, the pixel coordinates would be (0, 0).  To draw a 50x50 square at row 0 column 1, the pixel coordinates would be (50, 0).  See if you can think of a way to define the proper pixel x coordinate in terms of the row, and the proper pixel y coordinate in terms of the column.  Once you've figured that out, make a nested loop that iterates over every row-column coordinate, drawing a shape each time.
Here's an example of how that might look:

Say I want to iterate over every pair of numbers from 0 - 9...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
       // do something with i and j
    }
}
```

Do something similar for rows and columns.  If you need more guidance, you should take a look at some basic Java tutorials, like [these](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)